# I m getting a Token=with error in sql server ce

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm getting a Token=with error in sql server ce

```
with temp 
as 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY BiilDate) AS Number
        ,BiilDate
        , DATENAME(dw, BiilDate) as day 
    from 
        Bill 
    where 
        BiilDate >= DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()) 
    AND 
        BiilDate < GETDATE() 
) 
SELECT 
    day
    , COUNT() TotalCount 
FROM 
    temp 
GROUP BY 
    day 
HAVING 
    COUNT() >= 1 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) desc
```

Comment: At face value, I would not use "day" as a column - likely to be reserved in many cases - rather alias it as something else (or put square brackets around).  Also, normally COUNT(*).

Answer (score 0):

Sql ce does not support CTEs or row_number

Comment: So can you tell me how to modifies this query according to sqlce